# Algorithm to put find a similar matrix under reduced form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, change-of-basis

I would like to prove that the following algorithm to find a similar matrix under reduced form, that is a triangular one (it includes Jordan normal form), works but there is one step putting me in trouble.

For the seek of completeness I give all the necessary context to understand my question.

We are working on $E$ a finite dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field. We consider $f$ an endomorphism on $E$.

The algorithm proceeds as follows:

For each eigenvalue $\lambda_k$, we start by finding a basis $(v_1,…, v_p)$ of the eigenspace $F(\lambda_k)$. In many cases this is not sufficient (algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda_k$ greater than the dimension of $F(\lambda_k)$). Instead, we will « complete » the basis $(v_1,…, v_p)$ in order to find a basis of the spectral eigenspace of $\lambda_k$ denote $S(\lambda_k)$ (definition given below) which contains $F(\lambda_k)$.

For this, we take a linear combination of the basis (denote $b_{p+1}$) and seek for $w_{p+1}$ satisfying

$$
(f-\lambda_k I)(w_{p+1}) = \sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i v_i = b_{p+1}
$$

Then we add $w_{p+1}$, **which is linearly independent of the basis**,  to the basis $(v_1,…,v_p)$ and we continue by taking a linear combination of $(v_1,…,v_p,w_{p+1})$ (denote $b_{p+2}$) such that it is linearly independant of $b_{p+1}$ and we seek for a solution $w_{p+2}$ of

$$
(f-\lambda_k I)(w_{p+2}) = b_{p+2}
$$

And we follow this procedure until we get a family of linearly independent vectors $(v_1,…,v_p,w_{p+1},…,w_{p+k})$ with cardinality equal to the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda_k$.

By doing this, we determine a basis of $S(\lambda_k)$ since a well known theorem states that (for finite dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field) the dimension of the space $S(\lambda_k)$ is equal to the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda_k$.

My question is about the sentence in bold: I am not able to find the argument proving that the vectors $w_{p+1}$ that we determine by using this procedure are linearly independent of the family $(v_1,….,v_p)$. Can you give a hint to help me prove this please?

Thank you a lot!

---

Some definitions:

1- $v$ ($\neq 0_{E}$) is a spectral eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ if there exists $n\geq 1$ such that $(f-\lambda I)^n(v) = 0_{E}$ where $f^n$ denote the composition, $n$ times, of $f$ with itself with the convention that $f^0= I$ where $I$ is the identity mapping.

2- $S(\lambda)$ is the spectral eigenspace associated to $\lambda$, it is the set of all the spectral eigenvectors of $\lambda$.

---

**This contains possibly lot of mistakes sorry.**

The linear combination of the basis $(v_1,…,v_p)$ (denote $b_{p+1}$) has to be taken such that it is a non zero linear combination.

Then for the next step : the linear combination $b_i$ of $(v_1,…,v_p,.., w_{i-1})$ ($i\geq p+2$) should be such that they are linearly independant of the previous $b_k$ ($p+1\leq k<i$).

It is possible because at each step, $b_{i+1}$ is a linear combination of $(v_1,…,v_p,…w_i)$ while $b_{i}$  is a linear combination of $(v_1,…,v_p,…w_{i-1})$

---

**Seeing that I have some difficulty to propose such procedure to determine the reduced form of a similar matrix using the result I have stated about the spectral eigenspace. If you have some recommendations on how to perform such a task it would help me a lot. Thank you.**

Comment: What does this all have to do with row operations (only) and reduced echelon form?

Comment: That was an error. The aim being to get a triangular matrix similar to the one of interest, I thought reduced echelon form was the good word for such a matrix.

Comment: Absolutely not. Reduced echelon form has nothing to do with similarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an answer, but it was too long for a comment. Im not sure I follow what you are doing. You write "For this, we take a linear combination of the basis (denote +1) " but it is not clear what linear combination you are taking, and how do you know that there will exist a solution $w_{p+1}$ (the $f-\lambda_k$ has less than full rank)  . But in any case, if the $w_{p+1}$ you find is some linear combination of the $v_1, \ldots, v_p$, say $$w_{p+1}=\sum c_iv_i$$ then apply $f-\lambda_k I$ to both sides of this to get
$$(f-\lambda_kI)w_{p+1} = \sum c_i(f-\lambda_k)v_i =0$$ since the $v_i$ are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda_k$.

Basically, I think you may want to look at the spaces
$$V_j(\lambda_k)=\{ v \mid (f-\lambda_kI)^jv=0\}$$
so $V_1 \subseteq V_2\subseteq ...$.

But I'm not sure how all this related to reduced echelon form, which is about row operations, and this eigenstuff is Jordan decomposition ... but I just being ignorant.

Comment: Thank you a lot for taking the time to write this ! First you are right this has nothing to do with reduced echelon form, sorry. 

On the justification of why there is a solution $w_{p+1}$ you are right I lack precision. The idea I have is that we seek for $w_{p+1}$ not being an eigenvector of $\lambda_k$ (otherwise, we cannot add $w_i$ to the initial basis $(v_1,…,v_p)$ since it will be a linear combination of this basis) but it is not a proof I agree.  How works you argument about the rank of $f-\lambda I$ please ? I am not sure to have inderstood it well.

Comment: Also the point being unclear about how do we take the linear combination has been added in the question, but I have difficulty to justify these step. I think that the « algorithm I am seeking » is not that good for the moment

Comment: Also, just to clarify something that seems not clear in my post : this is the image of $w_{p+1}$ by the endomorphism $f-\lambda_k I$ which is a linear combination of the basis $(v_1,…,v_p)$ not $w_{p+1}$.

Comment: yes, that was clear, and your question was whether $w_{p+1}$ is linearly independent/dependent on the $v_i$'s, and so that was saying if $w_{p+1} = \sum c_iv_i$ and applying $f-\lambda_kI$ shows that the $\alpha_i$ in your notation must be $0$...and that proves that the $w_{p+1}$, if non-zero, is linearly independent of the $v_i$ ... which is what you wanted.

Comment: All right very sorry your answer was clear enough on this point thank you a lot ! Now I will focus on the existence of a solution $w_i$ as you pointed out in your answer. In any case thank you a lot !